# Streaming YouTube live into ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, youtube, live-streaming

hello I use ionic 4 with streamingMedia poir reading on links of videos .mp4 everything is fine but I want to do it with a video broadcast live on youtube, I do not receive an error but it does not start reading. is it possible to do it? P.s: I saw the native cordova youtube but will it give me the possibility, if yes will it allow me to hide the titles and others? Thank you for helping me please.